# Creating nxn bounding boxes across map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extents

I'm trying to implement a clustering solution for a Google Maps JavaScript application where I create nxn bounding boxes at a current position.

I've tried to draw what I'm trying to implement

[image]

(I couldn't draw accurate boxes in Gimp!).

The boxes are to be redrawn upon each movement of the map (so they won't be fixed to a single position or height). In the image example there would be a 4x3 series of bounding boxes. What I plan on doing is iterate over each bounding boxes and perform an ElasticSearch query on that bounding box and place a marker within that box of how many results there are for that section. Which should be faster than returning thousands of points in a GeoJSON response and trying to cluster the markers.

What I can't figure out, or find examples by others, is how to calculate the positions of each bounding box/rectangle.
Also, I'm not sure if a defined 4x3 would always be the best solution, viewing at a higher level may require fewer boxes than that at a lower (zoomed in) level.
How can I starting from the top left of the viewable map draw n bounding box/rectangle across and and below?